# Executing method outside the AWT thread

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

Ok, first of all, I'm sorry for the stupid title but I have no idea how to describe this problem better.

So, let's say that I have my GUI running on the AWT thread, and user clicks a button. When that happens, I would like to call a method that cannot be run in the AWT thread, but rather in a normal thread.

Here are my thoughts so far:

1) Lock AWT-thread and make it wait until AWT thread cally notify()

2) Create thread pool containing single thread and submit method to the pool.

Anyway, I don't know if there is a better way to handle this, so I hope you guys can help.

Comment: The AWT thread is called the EDT. Why can't you call your method on the EDT? Note that you can never call `wait()` on the EDT. Doing so will freeze the GUI. See also https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html

Comment: you have to accept that 1. (Lock AWT-thread and make it wait until AWT thread) is separate queue (EventDisptachThread - EDT) designated for AWT/Swing APIs, 2. all events should be created in workers thread, then the result / object / value for AWT/Swing GUI must be put in EDT queue by using invokeLater / methods implemented in SwingWorker, 3. there isn't something else, this logics is simple